# How to use the microphone with Flash on Windows 8 with IE10?

Tags: flash, windows-8, internet-explorer-10, microphone

On all other combinations of Windows and browsers when a user on my site attempts to invoke the flash microphone there is a flash permissions dialog that appears, which can then be accepted to allow recording.  On Windows 8 with IE10 the dialog doesn't appear and the microphone is inaccessible.  Is there some sort of work around for this?

Comment: If this is in the "Metro" IE10 there is no workaround. Flash is not allowed. Users will need to open the page with the Desktop version of IE

Comment: Are you getting the solution for this?